# Spark dataframe udf No TypeTag available

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to extend `spark` `ml` pipeline model with a filter transformer, after

```
abstract class RuleFilter[IN, T <: RuleFilter[IN, T]]
    extends RuleTransformer with HasInputCol  {
  // def filterFuntion: String
  /** @group setParam */
  def setInputCol(value: String): T = set(inputCol, value).asInstanceOf[T]

  protected def createFilterFunc: IN => Boolean

  override def transform(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    transformSchema(df.schema, logging = true)
    val transformUDF = udf[Boolean, IN](this.createFilterFunc)
    df.filter(transformUDF(df($(inputCol))))
  }
}
```

this code did not compile with an error:

```
 No TypeTag available for IN
[error]     val transformUDF = udf[Boolean, IN](this.createFilterFunc)
```

how do I let this work?

I need it to work with some explicit defined type in  inherit class such as

```
class PriceFilter extends RuleFilter {
    def createFilterFunc(val: Double) = val > 500
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the compiler explicitly that you want a [`TypeTag`](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html) for type `In`:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
abstract class RuleFilter[In: TypeTag, T <: RuleFilter[In, T]]
```

Comment: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/Transformer.scala#L82， but this UnaryTransformer works fine without explicitly TypeTag, how did this works?

Comment: What is `udf`? What does it do with the type?